# High CPU usage when using Lightroom + Dual Monitor?

Tags: lightroom

Wasn't sure if I should ask this question here or at another part of stackexchange, but I figured there would be more people using Lightroom here.

I just purchased a second monitor and have noticed that when I combine the second monitor with Lightroom my CPU usage goes up way way high, more than 100%!

I am using:

Macbook Pro 2009
OSX Lion 10.7
Lightroom 3.3

Is there anyone else experiencing this? Thanks

Comment: What resolution are you running the secondary monitor at?

Comment: It's 1920 x something. Sorry I am not currently using the monitor.

Comment: Wish I could get more than 100% CPU usage out of my CPU!  ;)  Sorry, couldn't resist.

Comment: Haha I know. Well I just read what the Activity Monitor says :) Should I reduce the resolution or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current version of Adobe Lightroom is 3.5, if you are on 3.3 I would first recommend **updating to the 3.5 version**.

The Macbook Pro mid-2009 13" model came with 2GB of ram standard, I would be worried that if you only have that installed, you are already at the minimum system requirements for Lightroom. To run Lightroom well I would personally recommend **at least 4GB of ram**, 8 if possible on a 64bit system. It is possible that your system may be trying to swap out physical memory with the swap file and that would increase your processor usage I believe.

Another question I have, is that you stated that your CPU usage is over 100%. What exactly is happening on your PC that has you concerned? Is the actual performance of Lightroom poor?

To help diagnose I would turn off all other applications after restarting the machine, and make sure it isn't an issue after a restart. This may help to find a memory leak within the application. If you are still having issues with Lightroom, I think your best bet is the Adobe Forums.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Fortunately I do have 4GB of DDR3 installed :) My concern is when I start using dual monitor Lightroom the laptop's fan starts spinning real hard, which means it's hot inside. I'm afraid of overheating. Is that silly? I will try updating to the latest Lightroom. Thank you!

Comment: I wouldn't worry about the fan, if it is running, that means it is doing its job. It's when your computer is working really hard and your fan doesn't kick on that I would start to worry! Like I am saying, 8GB would be better, and a non-laptop would also be better. Dual high resolution monitors, and large image editing on a laptop isn't exactly casual use, it is quite demanding!

Comment: Hahah yeah I suppose so. My laptop's res is only 1280x800 though. In any case, maybe I should get an iMac or a Mac Mini...